# How to ordering the divs Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How I can manage the orders of divs?

What I've now:
[image: What I have now.]

What I need:
[image: What I need]

**Code:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 bg-info">
        test <br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 bg-info">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 bg-info">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 bg-info">
        test </br></br></br></br></br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 bg-info">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about order in mobile screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it must be done without any change in current `HTML`, you can add Bootstrap's class `pull-right` to the right blocks.

Your code structure should be:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">test</div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">test</div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.bg-info {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 bg-info">
    test <br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right bg-info">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right bg-info">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right bg-info">
    test <br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 bg-info">
    4
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Example http://www.bootply.com/2sZeyGLJk3

Answer (score 0):

Every row has 12 units of space. so you can use nested divs to achieve the ovjective

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
           //first box first column
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
          //second box first column
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
           //first box second column
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
          //second box second column
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-12">
          //third box second column
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily change the order of grid columns with .col-md-push-* and .col-md-pull-* modifier classes. Take a look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) for more info.

Comment: Without a code example, this should be a comment rather than an answer. But you're right on the method used to achieve what OP is looking for.